# Debug flag for jsp web application

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, web.xml

I have a jsp web application where I print the error stacktrace as follows:

```
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
```

but in production environment I do not want my application to print something. I want to put a global flag (Debug = true for example) . then I will update the codes like this

```
  if(debug) e.printStackTrace(System.out);
```

I have many pages in my application. Now where should i declare the debug variable ? I can put it in web.xml file but I am not sure if its safe or not.Thanks

Comment: you don't have some class, where you store global variables and paths to config files (not those like `web.xml` but directly for use in your application)?

Comment: Use a logging API like slf4j, log4j or java.util.logging. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a logging API like JB Nizet suggests. They are rather simple to use. Here's a small example to implement logging using Log4j from Apache (http://logging.apache.org/log4j) which is very popular.

All your classes would have an instance of logger ready

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

Then at places where you catch exceptions

```
catch (SQLException e) {
    log.debug(e);
}
```

Then just configure Log4j using `log4j.properties` in your `classpath`

```
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout

log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout
```

To turn of logging is then as simple as changing

```
log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout
```

What this means is that you're only interested in log statements that are at a level of warning or above (like error, or fatal). There are about six log levels: fatal, error, warn, info, debug and trace. When you set a level all log statements that log at a level below what you've specified are ignored.

Please, note that I've simplified things above. It's recommended to use `log4j.xml` instead of `.properties`. Latest APIs also allow you to gain some performance with a check done before logging

```
catch (SQLException e) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug(e);
}
```

But, the real selling point of using the framework instead of just checking a `Globals.DEBUG` flag before doing a `printStackTrace()` is that it's future proof. Say tomorrow if you have to log things to a file just switch from `ConsoleAppender` to a `FileAppender`. Want an email delivered on something `fatal` use an `SMTPAppender` for just this use case. Other appenders stay configured as they are.